# iOS 7 Transition - XCode 5 - Interface Builder - Three20

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I've currently an App (with a lot of View Controllers, ...) what uses the "discontinued" Facebook three20 Library and any storyboard, xib file.

Now I need to update this App, the Deployment Target will be iOS 7 and I have to build it with XCode 5.

So my questions:

- Is using the Storyboard a good Idea? Would you suggest me to recreate all View Controllers in the Interface Builder?

--

Another question: when adding a Label Programmatically using iOS 7 feature

`self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeAll;`

how do I set the Frame for this Element? Need I determine if I am in Landscape, Portrait and Add the 20+44 for example manually to the y-Axis to start under the NavBar or are there better ways to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Storyboards are good, and you should absolutely use them in any future app you make.  Whether or not you should rebuild a current app to use storyboards is a question of how big the app currently is, how much bigger it might get, how much longer you'll support it, etc.

If the app is already pretty massive and it won't necessarily grow much at all from here, it's probably not worth the effort to convert over to storyboards.

If the app is only a handful of view controllers, but you have big future plans for it, I'd take the time to convert it over to storyboards so that all the future development will go faster/easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't deny storyboards but I respect the custom view approach. It means I am creating my each & every component programmatically via code, be it a UILabel or a UITableView. Aligning code with ios7 specific requirements can also be handelled & controlled at granular level using custom View approach.

To your questions about setting frames for the element or detecting device orientation can very well be detected & adopted by writing code.

You can search more help as the information is available all around on programming aspects of iOS.